# How to change javascript call to index my pages naturally

Tags: javascript, php, indexing, google-crawlers

I have a serious problem indexing some of my sites pages even getting them on the sitemap. I asked someone on Google forums and he told me that by looking ont the source code of one of my pages like the brand page (http://www.kelklope.com/marque/liste-des-marques-all.html) it doesn't use normal linke and the link mechanism is a JavaScript function call which makes it hard for search engines to discover the brand pages naturally.

Here's the code of the file

```
<?php require_once('inc/header.php'); ?>
<body>
<script>
$('.category').click(function(){
        var idvalue = $(this).attr('id');
        if(idvalue =='category_all'){
            $("ul").hide();
            return false;
        }else{
            $("ul").hide();
            if($("ul."+idvalue).length){
                $("ul."+idvalue).show();
                $(this).addClass('categoryopen');
            }
        }
    });
    function changeProductByManufacture(categoryId,subCategoryId,MarqueId,MarqueName,sortBy,BoutiqueId){
        if(!sortBy || $.trim(sortBy) == '') sortBy = '';
        $(".flash").show();
        $(".flash").fadeIn(400);
        $(".flash").html("<img src=\"images/loader.gif\" />");
        if($.trim(MarqueId) == '' && $.trim(BoutiqueId) == ''){
            var MarqueId = $('#filterby').val();
            var dataString = 'categoryId='+categoryId+'&subcategoryId='+subCategoryId+'&marqueId='+MarqueId;
        }else{
            $(".category").removeClass("categorySel");
            $(".subcatspan").removeClass("subcategory_sel");
            $(".menu_sub_outer").hide();
            $("#marque_"+MarqueId).addClass("categorySel");
            var dataString = 'findmarqueId='+MarqueId;
            if(categoryId && $.trim(categoryId) != '')
                dataString = dataString + '&categoryId='+categoryId;
            if(BoutiqueId && $.trim(BoutiqueId) != '')
                dataString = dataString + '&findboutiqueId='+BoutiqueId;
                console.log(dataString);
            if(MarqueName && $.trim(MarqueName) != 'undefined' && $.trim(MarqueName) != '')
                var testUrl = "<?php echo SITEPATH.'marque/'; ?>"+MarqueName+"<?php echo '-'; ?>"+MarqueId+"<?php echo '.html'; ?>";
            if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined" && testUrl && $.trim(testUrl) != 'undefined'){
                objPage = 1;
                var obj = { Page: objPage, Url: testUrl };
                history.pushState(obj, obj.objPage, obj.Url);
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo SITEPATH; ?>ajax/ajaxListProduit.php?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
            data: dataString+'&sortBy='+sortBy,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
            $(".flash").hide();
                $("#list").html(result);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("html, body").scrollTop(50);
                }, 10);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    function changeProductByBoutique(categoryId,subCategoryId,boutiqueId,boutiqueName,sortBy){
        if(!sortBy || $.trim(sortBy) == '' || $.trim(sortBy) == 'undefined') sortBy = '';
        if(!boutiqueId || $.trim(boutiqueId) == '' || $.trim(boutiqueId) == 'undefined') MarqueId = '';
        $(".flash").show();
        $(".flash").fadeIn(400);
        $(".flash").html("<img src=\"images/loader.gif\" />");
        if($.trim(boutiqueId) == ''){
            var boutiqueId = $('#filterby').val();
            var dataString = 'categoryId='+categoryId+'&subcategoryId='+subCategoryId+'&boutiqueId='+boutiqueId;
        }else{
            $(".category").removeClass("categorySel");
            $(".subcatspan").removeClass("subcategory_sel");
            $(".menu_sub_outer").hide();
            $("#marque_"+boutiqueId).addClass("categorySel");
            var dataString = 'findboutiqueId='+boutiqueId;
            if(boutiqueName && $.trim(boutiqueName) != 'undefined' && $.trim(boutiqueName) != '')
                var testUrl = "<?php echo SITEPATH.'boutique/'; ?>"+boutiqueName+"-"+boutiqueId+"<?php echo '.html'; ?>";
            if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined" && testUrl && $.trim(testUrl) != 'undefined'){
                objPage = 1;
                var obj = { Page: objPage, Url: testUrl };
                history.pushState(obj, obj.objPage, obj.Url);
            }
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo SITEPATH; ?>ajax/ajaxListProduit.php?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
            data: dataString+'&sortBy='+sortBy,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
            $(".flash").hide();
                $("#list").html(result);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("html, body").scrollTop(50);
                }, 10);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
<div id="main">
    <?php require_once("inc/top.php"); ?>

    <div id="menu-left">
        <?php 
            if(isset($leftmarquefilters) && !empty($leftmarquefilters) && count($leftmarquefilters) >0){
                if(isset($leftmarquefilters['found_rows'])) unset($leftmarquefilters['found_rows']);
        ?>
            <div id="menu-cat">
                <div id="menu-bandeau" class="menu-bands">
                    <h1 class="rouge-degrade menu2"><?php echo 'Marques populaires'; ?></h1>
                    <div class="menu-ombre"> </div>
                    <div class="menu-lf ombre-shadow">  </div>
                    <div class="menu-rg sprite ombre-shadow coin-droite"> </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                    foreach($leftmarquefilters as $keys => $res) { ?>
                        <span>
                            <div class="outer-menu nosubmenu">
                                <a onClick="javascript:return changeProductByManufacture('','',<?php echo $res->id?>,'<?php echo mrpropreNoPlus($res->name) ?>');"  href="#" id="marque_<?php echo $res->id;?>" class="category <?php if(isset($_SESSION['MarqueListAll']) && $_SESSION['MarqueListAll'] == $res->id) echo 'categorySel'; ?>" title="<?php echo strtoupper($res->name);?>"> 
                                <div class="sel_sub">
                                    <span class="submenu_lf"></span>
                                    <div class="sel_md">
                                        <span class="leftmenu"><?php echo ( isset($res->name) && (strlen($res->name)>25) ? substr($res->name, 0,25).'...' : $res->name ) ;?></span>
                                        <span id="category_arrow_<?php echo $res->id;?>" class="sub_cat_indicator fright"> </span>
                                        <span class="arrow_down"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="submenu_rg"></span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            </div>
                        </span>
            <?php   } ?>
            </div>
        <?php }elseif(isset($leftboutiquefilters) && !empty($leftboutiquefilters) && count($leftboutiquefilters) >0){
                if(isset($leftboutiquefilters['found_rows'])) unset($leftboutiquefilters['found_rows']);
        ?>
            <div id="menu-cat">
                <div id="menu-bandeau" class="menu-bands">
                    <h1 class="rouge-degrade menu2"><?php echo 'Boutiques populaires'; ?></h1>
                    <div class="menu-ombre"> </div>
                    <div class="menu-lf ombre-shadow">  </div>
                    <div class="menu-rg sprite ombre-shadow coin-droite"> </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                    foreach($leftboutiquefilters as $keys => $res) { ?>
                        <span>
                            <div class="outer-menu nosubmenu">
                                <a onClick="javascript:return changeProductByBoutique('','',<?php echo $res->id?>,'<?php echo mrpropreNoPlus($res->name) ?>');"  href="#" id="boutique_<?php echo $res->id;?>" class="category <?php if(isset($_SESSION['BoutiqueAll']) && $_SESSION['BoutiqueAll'] == $res->id) echo 'categorySel'; ?>" title="<?php echo strtoupper($res->name);?>"> 
                                <div class="sel_sub">
                                    <span class="submenu_lf"></span>
                                    <div class="sel_md">
                                        <span class="leftmenu"><?php echo ( isset($res->name) && (strlen($res->name)>25) ? substr($res->name, 0,25).'...' : $res->name ) ;?></span>
                                        <span id="category_arrow_<?php echo $res->id;?>" class="sub_cat_indicator fright"> </span>
                                        <span class="arrow_down"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="submenu_rg"></span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            </div>
                        </span>
            <?php   } ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div id="menu-main">
        <div id="list">
        </div>
        <span style="padding-left:23%;" class="flash"></span>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>


</div>
<?php require_once("inc/footer.php") ; ?>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    changePaginationByListProduct(<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['listPageId']) ? $_SESSION['listPageId'] : '1');?>);
});
function changePaginationByListProduct(listPageId){
    <?php if(isset($_GET['marque']) && !empty($_GET['marque'])) { ?>
        var marque = '<?php echo (isset($_GET['marque']) ? $_GET['marque'] : '');?>';
        var dataString = 'listPageId='+ listPageId+'&marque='+marque;
    <?php }elseif(isset($_GET['boutique']) && !empty($_GET['boutique'])) { ?>
        var boutique = '<?php echo (isset($_GET['boutique']) ? $_GET['boutique'] : '');?>';
        var dataString = 'listPageId='+ listPageId+'&boutique='+boutique;
    <?php }else{ ?>
        var dataString = 'listPageId='+ listPageId;
    <?php } ?>
    $(".flash").show();
    $(".flash").fadeIn(400);
    $(".flash").html("<img src=\"images/loader.gif\" />");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo SITEPATH; ?>ajax/ajaxListAllProduit.php?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
        $(".flash").hide();
            $("#list").html(result);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("html, body").scrollTop(50);
            }, 10);
        }
    });

    return false;
}
function submitFilterPaginationByList(){
    var listPerpage = $('#paginationPerpage').val();
    <?php if(isset($_GET['marque']) && !empty($_GET['marque'])) { ?>
        var marque = '<?php echo (isset($_GET['marque']) ? $_GET['marque'] : '');?>';
        var dataString = 'listPageId=1'+ '&listPerpage='+ listPerpage +'&marque='+marque;
    <?php }elseif(isset($_GET['boutique']) && !empty($_GET['boutique'])) { ?>
        var boutique = '<?php echo (isset($_GET['boutique']) ? $_GET['boutique'] : '');?>';
        var dataString = 'listPageId=1'+ '&listPerpage='+ listPerpage +'&boutique='+boutique;
    <?php }else{ ?>
        var dataString = 'listPageId=1'+ '&listPerpage='+ listPerpage ;
    <?php } ?>
     $(".flash").show();
     $(".flash").fadeIn(400);
     $(".flash").html("<img src=\"images/loader.gif\" />");
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '<?php echo SITEPATH; ?>ajax/ajaxListAllProduit.php?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(result){
           $(".flash").hide();
                 $("#list").html(result);
                 setTimeout(function() {
                   $("html, body").scrollTop(50);
                 }, 10);
           }
      });

     return false;
}
```